# Will this copy the object or add a reference to it?

Tags: javascript, reference

Let's say I have the following object:

```
var lol = {
    section: {},
    other: {foo: 'bar', foob: 'baz'}
};
```

Now if I do the following:

```
lol.section.other = lol.other;
```

will a reference be made linking `section.other` to `other` or will the entire `other` object be copied and placed in `section`?

Comment: Why didn't you simply test it by adding a property via one reference and seeing if it was accessible via the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're creating two references to the same object.

Javascript objects are *never* implicitly copied.

Comment: Yeah, and in case you are interested, jQuery has a handy method, $.extend() which lets you make deep clones of objects (by passing true to the first argument). http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: You could mimic copying behavior by creating a new object and appending the keys/values., perhaps in a loop?

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't want copying to occur in this case.

Comment: what about slice? this will do the job at least for arrays. And Brian Huisman presents a solution for copying objects as well. http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165

Answer (score 2):

Like quite a few other OO languages, JavaScript also passes and assigns the object by reference therefore, you are only creating a new reference to an existing object.

Where JavaScript breaks away from other OO languages is in inheritance and in encapsulation. So be cautious in those areas.

Answer (score 1):

As SLaks said, javascript assigns objects as a reference (without copying).  It's easy to test or see yourself:

```
var lol = {
    section: {},
    other: {foo: 'bar', foob: 'baz'}
};

lol.section.other = lol.other;

lol.other.foo = 'test';
console.log(lol.section.other.foo);   // will be 'test', not 'bar'
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/r73LH/.