# Storing value in two variables and changing one affects both variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have  an object "a" and would like to duplicate it to "b"
 When I delete an element in "a" why is "b" also being affected?

```
var a  = {'apple':1,'orange':2,'grapes':3}
var b = a 

console.log(a,b)
delete b.apple
console.log(a,b)
```

Now a and b are the same. I only want the element in b to be deleted. 
How can I do this

Comment: This is a dup of many other answers.  I will go find a dup to mark it as such.

Comment: The reason is that `a` and `b` are both _references_ to the same object. You need to _clone_ the object to get what you need. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/2170192.

Comment: This question is not a dupe of the one linked.

Comment: Note that the linked question explains the mechanism of passing the value to a function. Not the values themselves which is what this question is asking.

Comment: @slebetman - I could literally find twenty dups that explain this.  Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11837596/816620 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576884/will-this-copy-the-object-or-add-a-reference-to-it/7576991#7576991 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427395/object-or-objectification/30427746#30427746 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595359/assigning-a-var-to-temp-var-doesnt-stop-origianal-var-from-changing/13595387#13595387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects and arrays in javascript are references. So when you do:

```
var b = a;
```

You're making another pointer to object `a`. You're not copying `a`.

If you want to make a copy of an object you can use `Object.create`:

```
var b = Object.create(a);
```

Comment: Seriously, you don't think there are at least 50 dups of this question?

Comment: @jfriend00: Sometimes it's quicker to just answer than find a good dupe. If I have time I'll find a dup

Comment: @jfriend00: I know a good answer for function arguments but I don't know of one for just variables.

Comment: @jfriend00: The answer pointed to by Alex above is a good example of not a good general purpose answer because it's jQuery specific. Even the non-jQuery answers to that question don't explain the WHY, which is what this question is asking.

Comment: @jfriend00: The answer you duped is another good example of not a good answer for this question. It's a different (but related) question.

Comment: `Object.create` does **not** make a shallow copy.

Comment: @torazaburo: Ah, I thought it did. Deleting that part of the answer.

Comment: @slebetman Thank you buddy. **You** actually solved my problem